# C# WebClient hanging instead of throwing an error

Tags: c#, json, webclient, qualtrics

I’m trying to post JSON to the [Qualtrics API](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/create-survey-distribution) to send a survey request.

This works fine when all of the necessary IDs are valid and I receive a response as below.

```
{"result":{"id":"EMD_0xpOmBl99999999"},"meta":{"httpStatus":"200 - OK","requestId":"a075f677-bbcf-45fb-bb7d-328999999999"}}
```

If I change one of the values to an invalid ID, the API should return a ‘400 Bad request’ error and a message telling you which value is incorrect e.g.

```
{"meta":{"httpStatus":"400 - Bad Request","error":{"errorMessage":"Invalid surveyId parameter. surveyLink must contain a valid survey","errorCode":"JP_2"},"requestId":null}}
```

However, in my C# app, I don’t receive the expected 400 error, the code just hangs on the WebClient.UploadString step indefinitely.

If post the same JSON using testing tool such as Poster, I get the expected response.

How can I fix this?

```cs
private static string TestSendQualtricsSurvey()
{
    string apiUrl = @"https://eu.qualtrics.com/API/v3/distributions";
    string listId = "ML_123123123";
    string surveyId = "SV_123123123";
    string libraryId = "UR_123123123";
    string messageId = "MS_123123123";
    string senderName = "Survey Sender";
    string senderEmail = "testing@email.com";
    string emailSubject = "Please take this survey";
    string contactId = "MLRP_123123123";
    string apiKey = "123123123";

    Survey survey = new Survey();
    survey.surveyLink = new SurveyLink() { surveyId = surveyId, type = "Individual" };
    survey.header = new Header() { fromEmail = senderEmail, fromName = senderName, subject = emailSubject };
    survey.message = new Message() { libraryId = libraryId, messageId = messageId };
    survey.recipients = new Recipients() { contactId = contactId, mailingListId = listId };
    survey.sendDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Survey));
        js.WriteObject(ms, survey);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);                
        string surveyJson = sr.ReadToEnd();

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            client.Headers.Add("X-API-TOKEN", apiKey);

            string response;

            try
            {
                //IT HANGS HERE
                response = client.UploadString(apiUrl, "POST", surveyJson);
                return response;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return response;
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: do you return anything from server if it throws an error?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, it just sits at the response = client.UploadString line until I kill it.